# How to remove first item and last item using python

Tags: python

How to remove first and last using python
value=A 0006 005C 0078 0030 0034 0046 0030 00

Comment: Presuming that this is a string and you are splitting by white space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from your description it is a bit unclear what "first and last" are in your example. if you mean the first and last "word", eg 'A' and '00' you yould use:

```
" ".join("A 0006 005C 0078 0030 0034 0046 0030 00".split()[1:-1])
```

this returns

```
'0006 005C 0078 0030 0034 0046 0030'
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use a list slice:

```
>>> a = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
>>> a[1:-1]
['two', 'three']
```

See [Good Primer for Python Slice Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation) for more details about how this notation works.

Answer (score 0):

value='A 0006 005C 0078 0030 0034 0046 0030 00'

value[1:-2-1]

You will get the result as

' 0006 005C 0078 0030 0034 0046 0030'